# Why can't my app find Firebase Functions?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I can't figure out why I keep getting the Swift warning: `Use of unresolved identifier 'Functions` on this line of my code: `let functions = Functions.functions()`

My imports for the viewController includes `import Firebase` and it works fine when I declare `let db = Firestore.firestore()` right above the line `let functions = Functions.functions()`

My podfile includes `pod 'Firebase/Functions'` and I've installed the pod.

I'm calling `functions` later using the following code and when I type "functions" it recommends adding .httpsCallable which leads me to believe that it actually does recognize the object "functions":

```
     func getData(){
        functions.httpsCallable("helloWorld").call(userData) { (result, error) in
            if let error = error {
              print(error)
            }

            if let data = result?.data {
                print(data)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Importing Firebase is not enough, one must also import FirebaseFunctions (despite what Swift thinks, see screenshot below). 
[image]